# Error with Internet Explorer and Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have this jquery ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/private_cloud/add_app/'+school_id+'/'+app_id,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        if(data.status == 1)
        {
            console.log(data.status);
        }
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

When I am using chrome, and firefox, this is working perfectly fine. But when I am using internet explorer, it shows in the console "1" but the data wasn't even inserted in the Database.

This is my code in PHP:

```
public function add_app($school_id = NULL, $app_id = NULL)
{
    if($this->School->save($get_school))
    {
        echo '{"status":"1"}';
    }
    else{
        echo '{"status":"0"}';
    }

    die;
}
```

Comment: jqxhr actually has a "status" variable that is already used in ajax (though deprecated now) to indicate success of the xhr request - it is in fact still used, you should stay away from this and use something like "myStatus" to send to the jqxhr data object, not use "status" as your property name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a request type so it's defaulting to GET therefore IE is (most probably) caching the response. Add

```
type: 'POST'
```

to your AJAX config object, eg

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/private_cloud/add_app/'+school_id+'/'+app_id,
    type: 'POST',
    // etc
```

Comment: although I thought using type: 'POST' is only for posting the data using .serialize() function. But anyways, it solved my problem. thanks again.